# jpost being performed last?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, post

I have a function that creates Google maps markers. I pass in data from a database query. Then I have the function perform another database query using one value as the foreign key. I am trying then to put all the results (the data from the first query and the data from the second query) into a string, which the marker will display in an infoWindow.

But somehow, the program views the string as "undefined" unless I build it outside of the $.post function for the second query. What's going on? Shouldn't the program be able to read that string?

Here is my code:

```
function createMarker(marker_id, point,street, neighborhood, date,map) {
            // Create the HTML text based on the values passed in from XML
            $.post('get_victimdata.php', {marker_id:marker_id},
                 function(victimdata){

                     objVictimdata = jQuery.parseJSON(victimdata);
                     markerhtml = "";
                      markerhtml += "<strong>Street: </strong>" + street + "<br>";
                      markerhtml += "<strong>Neighborhood: </strong>" + neighborhood + "<br>";
                      markerhtml += "<strong>Date: </strong>" + date + "<br><br>";
                     for (var i=0; i < objVictimdata.length; i++) {
                         var image_path = objVictimdata[i].image_path;
                         var image_height = objVictimdata[i].image_height;
                         markerhtml += "<strong>Victim Name: </strong>" + objVictimdata[i].name + "<br>";
                         markerhtml += "<strong>Age:</strong> " + objVictimdata[i].age + "<br>";
                         markerhtml += "<strong>Race:</strong> " + objVictimdata[i].race + "<br>";
                         markerhtml += "<strong>Gender:</strong> " + objVictimdata[i].gender + "<br>";
                         markerhtml += "<strong>Cause:</strong> " + objVictimdata[i].cause + "<br><br>";
                         console.log(markerhtml);

                     }//end for

            })//end post
            console.log(markerhtml);


            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            new google.maps.Size(12, 20),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(6, 20));

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: point,
              map: map,
              icon: image
            });

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); //initialize infoWindow
              // Add a click event to each marker which will open the HTML window
            marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: markerhtml
            });


            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                marker.infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

};//end create marker
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. The diffence is that I placed all statemetns following the call to $.post inside of the anonymous function which is fired after and only if the post succeeds. When you call $.Post, the function on the inside isn't ran until the post is complete, but execution still continues to the following statements while the post occurs in the background!

**Paraphrased** The inner anonymous function has been expanded to include most of the code. If you are unsure of the difference, try using a program like WinMerge which will show you the difference: [image: winmerge showing the difference]

```
function createMarker(marker_id, point,street, neighborhood, date,map) {
            // Create the HTML text based on the values passed in from XML
            $.post('get_victimdata.php', {marker_id:marker_id},
                 function(victimdata){

                     objVictimdata = jQuery.parseJSON(victimdata);
                     markerhtml = "";
                      markerhtml += "<strong>Street: </strong>" + street + "<br>";
                      markerhtml += "<strong>Neighborhood: </strong>" + neighborhood + "<br>";
                      markerhtml += "<strong>Date: </strong>" + date + "<br><br>";
                     for (var i=0; i < objVictimdata.length; i++) {
                         var image_path = objVictimdata[i].image_path;
                         var image_height = objVictimdata[i].image_height;
                         markerhtml += "<strong>Victim Name: </strong>" + objVictimdata[i].name + "<br>";
                         markerhtml += "<strong>Age:</strong> " + objVictimdata[i].age + "<br>";
                         markerhtml += "<strong>Race:</strong> " + objVictimdata[i].race + "<br>";
                         markerhtml += "<strong>Gender:</strong> " + objVictimdata[i].gender + "<br>";
                         markerhtml += "<strong>Cause:</strong> " + objVictimdata[i].cause + "<br><br>";
                         console.log(markerhtml);

                     }//end for
                    console.log(markerhtml);


                    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
                    new google.maps.Size(12, 20),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    new google.maps.Point(6, 20));

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: point,
                      map: map,
                      icon: image
                    });

                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); //initialize infoWindow
                      // Add a click event to each marker which will open the HTML window
                    marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content: markerhtml
                    });


                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                        marker.infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });


            })//end post

};//end create marker
```

Comment: @user1229001: Its not... why would I post the same exact code. I explained what the difference is anyway. Did you try it?

Comment: sorry - I've been gone over the long holiday weekend. Your solution worked! I understand what you did now. Thank you very much for your time and patience!